# Could not find gem 'grape-entity (~> 0.5.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine

Tags: kali-linux

while installing the gitlab, i got encounter with this error[image]

Comment: This is not a security question, but a Linux question.

Comment: Posting an image of the messages does little to help. Please copy and paste the text so that the messages can be read.